# How do I recalculate a probability matrix as each choice is made

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Lets say I have a set of people A,B,C,D and they will each be picked but their order matters. The probability that A will be picked first is 70%. And C getting picked 1st is only 12%. According to the matrix below.

```
    A      B      C      D
1   0.70   0.13   0.12   0.05
2   0.15   0.65   0.13   0.07
3   0.10   0.15   0.60   0.15
4   0.05   0.07   0.15   0.73
```

How do i recalculate the matrix of probabilities if C is chosen first, for instance? A should be more likely to be picked second than B, given that C was chosen 1st.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You first have to determine whether or not the process is memoryless. If it is, meaning that regardless of what happened until time $t_n$, at time $t_{n+1}$, A has a 70% chance of being picked first, 15% chance of being picked second, D has a 73% chance of being picked last, etc, then this is an example of a [Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) and the matrix you show is its [transition matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix). If so, then it doesn't matter who got picked at time 1. At time 2, the transition matrix remains the same. If it isn't memoryless, I do not think you have enough information to solve the problem, since you are only given one matrix which transitions from time $n$ to time $n+1$.</s>

**Edit** Upon further review, I believe that I made a mistake. I was assuming that one can go from any state to any state. After rereading your question, it seems that all of A, B, C, and D needs to be selected in any iteration before the process can start again, which makes it most definitely *not* a Markov chain. In that case, I believe the proper way to calculate the next step (still assuming independence) is to use the normalized submatrix obtained by removing the already selected point.

For example, assume that C is already chosen. The submatrix that remains is:
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
0.70 & 0.13 & \Diamond & 0.05\\
0.15 & 0.65 & \Diamond & 0.07\\
\Diamond & \Diamond & \Diamond & \Diamond\\
0.05 & 0.07 & \Diamond & 0.73
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Which becomes
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
0.70 & 0.13 & 0.05\\
0.15 & 0.65 & 0.07\\
0.05 & 0.07 & 0.73
\end{array}
\right]
$$

And when normalized
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
0.795 & 0.148 & 0.057\\ 
0.172 & 0.747 & 0.080\\ 
0.059 & 0.082 & 0.859 
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Giving a 79.5% chance for picking A second after picking C first.

Comment: What further information would I need to solve the problem if it isn't memoryless?

Comment: What is the probability for a two-stage jump, a three stage jump, etc.

Comment: Thx, I think I'll have to try another approach

Comment: I made a mistake, I believe. Sorry.

Comment: This was the first thing I tried, but the normalized matrix no longer adds to 100% in the columns. 'A' has a 102.6% chance of being picked and 'B' only has a 97.7% chance. If I normalize along the columns the rows no longer add up.

Comment: Why do feel the column sums are significant? It is the rows which determine the probability of which will be picked "next." Every letter has 100% chance of being picked, eventually, as you will end up with a length 4 string, correct?